# Method with more than 50 input variables?

Tags: android, database, variables, methods, input

I'm working on an application and have a little problem right now. Let me explain what is the purpose of this application:
- there is a main menu with different buttons (let's say 16 buttons). 
- each time the user clicks on a button, it sends a request to a database and display a listview of results with different results depending on the button you clicked.
- in the database, there is a column with a "category number". (actually there are 3 columns with CatNumbers but let's keep it simple).
- the request asks to display all the elements where this category number equals some values (these are the inputs of my method, called "myVariableN" sent from the MainActivity to the ListView activity via putExtra/getExtra).  In my ListViewActivity which displays the results:

```
private void displayListView() {
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    String title = bundle.getString("title", "Choose here :");
    int myVariable1 = bundle.getInt("myVariable1", 500);
    int myVariable2 = bundle.getInt("myVariable2", 500);
    int myVariable3 = bundle.getInt("myVariable3", 500);
    int myVariable4 = bundle.getInt("myVariable4", 500);
    int myVariable5 = bundle.getInt("myVariable5", 500);
    int myVariable6 = bundle.getInt("myVariable6", 500);
```

So what I have so far is this : if you click on button 1 for example, it sends 6 variables (myVariable1, 2, 3 ... 6) and ask to display all elements "WHERE CatNumber IN (myVariable1, myVariable2, ... myVariable6).

```
public Cursor findPoiInTable(int myVariable1, int myVariable2,
        int myVariable3, int myVariable4, int myVariable5, int myVariable6) 
{
    String inInterval = "(?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    String where = COL_CAT1 + " IN " + inInterval + " OR " + COL_CAT2
            + " IN " + inInterval + " OR " + COL_CAT3 + " IN " + inInterval;
    String[] whereArgs = new String[3 * 6];

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
    {
        whereArgs[6 * i] = Integer.toString(myVariable1);
        whereArgs[6 * i + 1] = Integer.toString(myVariable2);
        whereArgs[6 * i + 2] = Integer.toString(myVariable3);
        whereArgs[6 * i + 3] = Integer.toString(myVariable4);
        whereArgs[6 * i + 4] = Integer.toString(myVariable5);
        whereArgs[6 * i + 5] = Integer.toString(myVariable6);
    }
    Cursor c = myDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { KEY_ROWID,
            COL_NAME, COL_STREET}, where, whereArgs, null, null, null);
   return c; 
}
```

Problem is, out of these 16 buttons from the main menu, there are a few buttons which would require to get data from the database with a much bigger range of category numbers. For example, something like "SELECT .... FROM.... WHERE CatNumber IN (myVariable1, myVariable2, ..... myVariable**50**).
And unfortunately, the method must be the same for every button, no matter if there are 2 or 50 input variables.

I feel like if I do this, my method is gonna be too heavy and will slow down my whole application, because in most of the cases, even when the request will be supposed to find 2 or 3 CatNumbers, the method will be defined for 50 inputs or more so it will have to make the whole calculation every time.

What I was thinking about was:
**a/** Modifying my method with a IF statement, so for example, IF there are less than... let's say 6 variables sent, it will make the light method with only 6 myVariable input, ELSE, it's gonna run the heavy method with 50 inputs. So the heavy method will be used only in a few cases, the wrong thing is that even if there are only 7 inputs, it will run the heavy method. Or in the same kind of idea, I could send a boolean sent via putExtra and set to TRUE (for using the light method) and FALSE (and then it would use the heavy method).
**b/** Set the value by default to 500 (as done in my code), so only the specific myVariables have a value different than 500. And then my question is: **is it possible to define a method with 50 inputs and to make it only use the input whose value is different from a certain number, so the method isn't always too heavy to run?**  For example in the code above with the method, would it be possible to say to only look for two variables if the four other are equal to 500 (myVariable1 and myVariable2 instead of all the variables even if the whole method is defined for the rest?).
Thanks in advance !

Comment: I feel like you should spend some time trimming this question down to the bare-bones problem. That aside, you will *never* need a method with 50 parameters. Ever.

Comment: Encapsulate your values in Classes?

Comment: If you're using WHERE ... IN it looks like you should be passing an array to the method - is this possible?

Comment: isn't it better to have a method public Cursor findPoiInTable(String inInterval) and creating the inInterval on the other end. You can create this interval in displayListView().

Comment: Thanks for answering. @HoanNguyen I feel like this way would actually definitely be the easier and most efficient as it just looks for what is given in a first place. But in the method, I need to know how many elements there are in this String inInterval. Is there a tool to get it automatically, as inInterval.getNumberOfElements or something like this? Wouldn't an array be more convenient in the case we can't get the number of elements, as suggested by Sam ?

Comment: What method do you refer to? Does findPoiInTable is more complicated than what you post? You can have a variable to save the number of element when constructing the inInterval string.

Comment: @HoanNguyen : I am refering to the method findPoiInTable, because in my example, there are 6 variables and the part "for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)" with the 6 lines following. Meaning if I have an array of 50 variables, this part of the method (whereArgs) will have to be improved to adapt itself to the number of elements right? So I will consider sending two information via putExtra : String inInterval and int which will be the number of elements in this string.

Comment: No your inInterval will look like ("'" + myVar1 + "'", "'" + myVar2 + "'" ...) and you can put the whereArgs to be null.

Comment: Oh good to know ! Thanks a lot for your time, I am gonna try this way!

Comment: I did not notice that your variables are integer, so you may not need the literal at all. Just implement with the literal and then take it out see if it would work.

Comment: @HoanNguyen :  I have modified everything but the putExtra which always give me an error in the writing. Like : t.putExtra("inInterval", (1,2, 45, 32)); would be wrong, t.putExtra("inInterval", (""+ 1 + "", ""+ 45 + "")); also, etc. All these brackets make me confused in your example, can't find the right writing!

Comment: Which putExtra? Is it in the code above?

Comment: No I just put the getExtra in the code above. This getExtra is supposed to get the "inInterval" from the buttonListener. So in the listener of the button I define inInterval and send it to this other activity where the methode findPoiInTable(inInterval) will be called.

Comment: putExtra("inInterval", "(" + myVar1 + "," + myVar2 + "," + ... + ")");

Comment: Above I miss the closing parenthesis for putExtra the first time I commented. I cannot edit it again so make sure you have the extra parenthesis as above.

Comment: @HoanNguyen : i made all the changes, it's ok, it does work perfectly now. Everything is much more simple in the program now, I just have to define all my listeners. I am really grateful for your help and your time ! Thanks so much =)

Answer (score 2):

You want this --

```
void myVariableMethod( int... catIds ) {
    for( int catId : catIds ) {
        Log.d( "Output", "catId: " + catId );
    }
}
```

Adding the ellipsis after the type in a method declaration will allow you to pass any number of the same type of arguments to the method. `catIds` is then actually an `int[]` array within the method body.

You can call this method as follows:

```
myVariableMethod( 1, 2, 3, 4 );
myVariableMethod( 1 );
myVariableMethod( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 );
myVariableMethod( 1, 2, 3, 4, 100, 101, 102 );
```

A more elegant solution to your problem would be to use a `List<Integer>`, or `Set<Integer>` and add those ids as you evaluate your buttons. Lastly, you would pass the list to the method and evaluate it properly.

My gut says that you can improve your database design to avoid the `WHERE ... IN` construct entirely, but that's difficult to determine without seeing the ERD.

Comment: I can't actually modify the database, I have to work with it and there are already more than 8k records inside. I'm gonna try this way, pass an array of my variables any time I click on a button and rewrite my method to make it have this array for input instead of variables themselves. Yet, I'm not sure I understood the code you posted: does it mean this code is required when for example you use a method whose input is an array but when the number of elements is not always the same?

Comment: Edited the answer. You can call the method with as few or as many parameters as you like. Within the method, you'll receive an array if the correct length.

Answer (score 1):

surely you can use the define you method with a Vararg as :

```
 public Cursor findPoiInTable(int ... myVariable) 
{

    //construct String from myVariable array
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("(");
    for (int i : myVariable)
    {
        sb.append(",?");
    }
    sb.append(")");

    String inInterval = sb.toString();

    String where = COL_CAT1 + " IN " + inInterval + " OR " + COL_CAT2
            + " IN " + inInterval + " OR " + COL_CAT3 + " IN " + inInterval;

    String[] whereArgs = new String[3 * myVariable.length];

 int j = 0
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
    {
        whereArgs[6 * i + j] = Integer.toString(myVariable[j++]);
        whereArgs[6 * i + j] = Integer.toString(myVariable[j++]);
        whereArgs[6 * i + j] = Integer.toString(myVariable[j++]);
        whereArgs[6 * i + j] = Integer.toString(myVariable[j++]);
        whereArgs[6 * i + j] = Integer.toString(myVariable[j++]);
        whereArgs[6 * i + j] = Integer.toString(myVariable[j++]);
    }
    Cursor c = myDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { KEY_ROWID,
            COL_NAME, COL_STREET}, where, whereArgs, null, null, null);
   return c; 
}
```